# Prove or disprove the identity $(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D) = (A \cap D) \cup (C \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Consider the sets $A, B, C, D$. Prove or disprove:
>   $$(A \cap  B) \cup  (C \cap  D) = (A \cap  D) \cup  (C \cap  B)$$

It seems I found how to prove **and** disprove this problem..?

I saw that by letting $A=\{1,3\}$, $B=\{3,7\}$, $C=\{8,9\}$, $D=\{9,0\}$, the LHS is left to $\{3\}\cup \{9\}$, while the RHS is left to $\emptyset \cup  \emptyset$.

I also tried proving it using laws.

$(A \cap  B) \cup  (C \cap  D)$

$(A \cap  B) \cup  (D \cap  C)$ -Commutative

$ A \cap  (B \cup  D) \cap  C$   - associative

$A \cap  (D \cup  B) \cap  C$  -Commutative

$(A \cap  D) \cup  (B \cap  C)$ -associative

$(A \cap  D) \cup  (C \cap  B)$ -Commutative

What is wrong with any of these proofs?

Comment: I tried discrete, mathematics, sets, union, intersect, but I need more reputation..

Comment: I edited the post. Popular tags are listed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags). A tutorial on math notation is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020)

Comment: what do you mean by set $D(9,0)$? Are you saying $(9,10)$? If so then $A \cap B=\phi$ and $C \cap D=\phi$.

Comment: @Anurag A Sorry, I'm trying to saying what the sets contain. I just made up numbers to prove the point, was trying to say that C has the elements 8 and 9, and the D set has the elements 9 and 0, ( or 9 and whatever other number..?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The associative law applies only when the operators are all the same:
\begin{align*}
A\cap(B\cap C) &= (A\cap B)\cap C &&\text{legit} \\
A\cap(B\cup C) &= (A\cap B)\cup C &&\text{not legit}
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh I feel silly. Thanks a lot for the needed help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove it with any law, because the equality is false, in general.

Suppose $A=B$ and $C=D$; then the left-hand side is just $A\cup C$. Now suppose $A\cap C=\emptyset$: then the right-hand side is $\emptyset$. Here's the needed example:

$A=B=\{0\}$, $C=D=\{1\}$

Answer (score 0):

The statement isn't true. Take $A = [0,1]$, $B = [1,2]$, $C = [3,4]$, and $D = [4,5]$

Then $(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D) = \{1,4\}$

But $(A \cap D) \cup (C \cap B) = \emptyset$